# Defining product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

It's very basic doubt but I am little confused about product of vector spaces. I didn't get satisfactory result  on internet. While defining product of vector spaces, do we need both vector spaces over same field ? I don't think so. Means, let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ and let $W$ be a vector space over field $K$, then $V × W$ will be vector space over field $F × K$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F \times K$ isn't a field (why?). Indeed $V \times W$ is a module over the ring $F \times K$.

Comment: Oh, multiplicative inverse property fails. So, in order to define product of vector spaces, we need same field right ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of direct product.

Comment: But $V \times W$ is a vector space over a common subfield of F and K.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly multiply the fields defined because the dimension of the resulting vector space have to be the addition of the dimensions of the vector spaces given, you may want to refer [Direct product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectProduct.html).So, the fields that the given vector spaces defined on  have to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

To define the product of two vector spaces as a vector space they must be over the same field. E.g. if $(a,b)$ is in one field and $(c,d,e)$ is in the other $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is in the product space. Then $\alpha(a,b,c,d,e)=(\alpha a,\alpha b,\alpha c,\alpha d,\alpha e)$.